# Synchronizing threads in Java

Tags: java, android, multithreading, synchronized, concurrentmodification

I have two threads modifying the same object, lets say MyObject, and so have synchronized the object. But in one of the threads another object is modified and in so doing has to call MyObject.

I.e.

```
public void run(){
   synchronized(MyObject){
             ...
            anotherObject.modify();//<----calls MyObject
             ...
    }
 }
```

This is causing ConcurrentModificationExceptions. I don't know how to solve this. If I don't synchronize, I get exceptions as both threads try to call MyObject. How can I fix this?

UPDATE: The code is for the Android device. I didn't mention it before, because there are no Android specific objects in play here.
The LogCat output isn't very helpful

> 02-03 02:47:43.660: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5258): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
>   02-03 02:47:43.670: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5258): java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
>   02-03 02:47:43.670: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5258):     at java.util.AbstractList$SimpleListIterator.next(AbstractList.java:64)
>   02-03 02:47:43.670: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5258):     at com.jjg.myapp.gameunit.findEnemy(MoveableUnit.java:656)//<---in this method Gamestate's collections are iterated through
>   02-03 02:47:43.670: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5258):     at com.jjg.myapp.gameunit.update(GameUnit.java:416)

The Object that I was trying to synch is essentially a GameState called gs. It houses an assortment of ArrayLists, arrays and other objects. gs is not static.

The method above where the problem occurs is:

```
for(GameUnit gu : this.getBase().getGameState().getAllUnits()){//<---this is the problem line.
//do some stuff...
 }
```

getAllUnits returns an ArrayList of GameUnits (including the GameUnit calling the method - I don't need an iterator as no objects are deleted or created).

Comment: Show us the real code, and the stack trace of the exception. The ConcurrentModificationException could have nothing to do with multiple threads.

Comment: There's too little detail to offer specific advice relevant to your circumstances. Show us your actual code.

Comment: I updated it. I hope the updated information is useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're really asking the same question as this: [Thread-safe iteration over a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4517653/thread-safe-iteration-over-a-collection).

The simplest solution is to copy the list before iterating through it:

```
for(GameUnit gu : new ArrayList<GameUnit>(this.getBase().getGameState().getAllUnits()))
```

Alternatively you can synchronize on the collection itself (note that for this to work, you also have to synchronize wherever you're modifying the "all units" list):

```
ArrayList<GameUnit> units = this.getBase().getGameState().getAllUnits())
synchronized (units) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A `ConcurrentModificationException` is often thrown if an collection is modified while using an iterator on it. -- So my you are mislead by the name and just search for the wrong problem.

Comment: I thought using an iterator prevents Con.Mod.Ex.'s? I'm confused.

Comment: @JJG:Actually it is the `iterator` that throws such an exception once it detects a modification.You are perhaps confusing it with the fact that you can `remove` from a collection using an iterator

Comment: BTW: And a foreach loop is based on interators too.

Comment: @JJG, from the Javadoc: "if the list is structurally modified at any time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the iterator's own remove or add methods, the iterator will throw a ConcurrentModificationException."  What gave you the idea that iterators _avoid_ CMEs?

Answer (score 0):

> I have two threads modifying the same object, lets say MyObject, and
>   so have synchronized the object.

No you don't.Only 1 thread is modifying `MyObject` the other is blocked.

> But in one of the threads another object is modified and in so doing
>   has to call MyObject.

The thread that has the lock will go again since the lock is rentrant.

As comments stated the code you post is not showing what you actually do to get that exception.

Is `MyObject` a `Collection`? Are you modifying this collection elsewhere concurrently i.e. without proper synchronization?
Or perhaps iterating?
In this case you would get the exception you say

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this, it is circular logic.

You either have to get rid of the threads altogether and determine an explicit order of evaluation or share data in some other way.

One possible strategy is to put the call "anotherObject.modify" into a separate runnable thread like this:

```
  SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
       anotherObject.modify();
    }
  });
```