# is for-each iteration thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, for-loop, iterator

I have one situation in multithreaded environment where there is no logical problem, but I am concerned if the iterator of java Set could break in some corner case. I don't know if this would crash after a while or not:

```
class Bar{
    AtomicLong a = 0;
    AtomicLong b = 0;

    public void addA(int value){
        a.addAndGet(value);
    }
    public void addB(int value){
        b.addAndGet(value);
    }
}

class Foo{
    Set<Bar> bars = new CopyOnWriteArraySet();

    public void addBarData(Bar bar){
        if (!bars.add(bar)){
            for (Bar b: bars){
                if (bar.equals(b)){
                    b.addA(bar.a);
                    b.addB(bar.b);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem might be if two threads are calling addBarData(barInstance) at the near time, one is entering inside ifs body, and start to iterate for-each, but the other adds another element into the set at that moment. Would for-loop (or iterator) crash because of the change of elements number or not?

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4517653/thread-safe-iteration-over-a-collection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in your question looks thread-safe because:

- Class `Bar` uses `AtomicLong` which is atomic and thread-safe.
- The `CopyOnWriteArraySet` is thread-safe as well (it copies whole array on every write operation).

So it all is thread-safe, you will not get `ConcurrentModificationException`, and the result of this code is predictable, because the collection you iterate through is in fact immutable.

Comment: My concern is about iterating over set that is growing with new elements (other threads might add new ones)

Comment: Right now other threads can add new elements but it will be visible only for threads that start iteration after add operation ends.
If you need to see new elements immediately you cannot use `CopyOnWriteArraySet` but (for example 'LinkedHashSet`). Using `LinkedHashSet` you will need also add synchronization block.

Comment: This answer seems to imply that thread safety is composable.  It's not. If a(X), b(Y), and c(X) are all thread-safe methods, then a method, d() that does nothing but call a(x), b(y), and c(x) still might _not_ be thread safe.  The a(x) and c(x) methods might guarantee to leave x in a 'safe' state no matter what happens in other threads, and likewise for b(y), but 'safety' for d() might mean preserving an important relationship _between_ x and y. With no mutual exclusion, it might not be able to do that when called from more than one thread at the same time.

Comment: Of course **thread safety is not composable**. This code is thread-safe unless someone changes references to AtomicLongs.

Answer (score 3):

No, for-each loop is just a compiler magic that is equivalent to iteration with `Iterator` for collection and with index for arrays. It does not add any other effects like thread safety.

Comment: Do you mean it wouldn't crash, or it would? I am using CopyOnWriteArraySet, would it protect this from crashing?

Comment: Crashing would only happen if you modify the collection. Nothing in your example seems to be modifying the collection, so it won't crash. If something is modifying the collection you will need to restrict using a lock or use a copy-on-write or similar collection.

Comment: But you are not able to modify the collection you iterate through.