# restart and IndexOutOfBoundsException strange reason, How can I avoid this in the future?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, indexoutofboundsexception

In 99% of cases working properly, sometimes as the application is minimized and I reopen it gets exception:

`java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0 at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException`

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); ++i) 
{                  
   description.setText(list.get(i).getStreet()); //this line Exception
}
```

I run this in `onStart()` method:

What is the reason?
How can I avoid this in the future?

Comment: do you clear the list onPause ?

Comment: Concurrent modification seems to be the only option.

Comment: @Prag'sシ Irrelevant.

Comment: give it a try... may be somehow..

Comment: @Prag'sシ The value of the "step" expression is discarded. You shouldn't program by "maybe".

Comment: Yeah Thanks For motivation.. @MarkoTopolnik

Comment: Should I clear all variables in OnPause ?

Comment: why do you use `++i`?

Comment: why not? Old habits from c++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using list within different threads can be a reason. If you are using not synchronized List implementation replace it with synchronized one:

```
List list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList());
```

or `Vector` , or `CopyOnWriteList` .

**Edited:**

Thanks for the comments! They are correct.

The simplest for me seems to be use [CopyOnWriteArrayList](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) and iterate over it with for-each loop. Or you can use any other option from this answer: [Thread-safe iteration over a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4517653/thread-safe-iteration-over-a-collection)

Comment: That won't help because synchronization granularity will be too small. OP needs to synchronize the entire list traversal.

Comment: Using iterator rather than indexes would give fast fail with ConcurrentModificationException.

Comment: It's true I have a thread in the background, it could be the reason?
`java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
            at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
            at java.util.ArrayList.get`